# What are "cell variables" in Python?

Tags: python, closures

I've heard the term "cell variable" for many places(e.g. when people talking about the `super()` magic of Python and closure), but I can't find its definition on this site or in the documentation.

So, I think this question is necessary: What's a "cell variable"?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/cell.html ?

Comment: @RicardoSilveira Yes, I've found this page. But I think it talks about "implementation", and I expect answers from a more abstract level.

Comment: From what is available in the documentation, I'd define cell variables as the objects created for variables accessed from multiple different scopes. Then how it works ? I'd say with the counter sctructure, as defined in the docs.